# Why are there two perfect forms of 'verwenden'?

Tags: perfect-tense, preterite

I looked on LEO for the perfect form of 'verwenden', but it says 'verwendet/verwandt'.

The same thing also applies in the preterite.

Why are there two different words to mean 'used'?

Comment: I guess there is some historical linguist who can explain why these two forms exist. But I doubt that knowing the answer would be of much practical value.

Answer (score 6):

In the corresponding entry to the word stem [wenden](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GW17160#XGW17160) the Grimm dictionary states the following:

> Während das Niederländische [...] den 'Rückumlaut' der Präteritalformen durch Ausgleich beseitigt hat, herrscht im Neuhochdeutsch Doppelformigkeit: wandte, wendete; gewandt, gewendet [..] wendete oder wandte [...]. Beim Partizip ist diese bereits im Althochdeutsch (giwant [...] neben unsynkopiertem und daher umgelautetem giwentit [...]) zu beobachten; beim Präteritum hingegen breiten sich die Umlautformen erst im spätmittelalterlichen Deutsch aus, vor allem im Oberdeutschen [...]. In Luthers Bibelübersetzung finden sich nebeneinander [...]: wand- (89 %), wendet- (11 %); gewand (68 %), gewendet (32 %).

They describe the loss of irregular forms for wenden as a loss of the [Rückumlaut](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%BCckumlaut), a concept that today is disputed but kept for practical  reasons.

According to this the irregular wordforms for *wenden* (*wandt, gewandt*) were only partly lost over time. They also state that for the past participle this already took part in Old High German (*giwentit, giwant*) and was further passed on in medieval German and by Luthers translation of the Holy Bible.

In compound nouns we also see this duality (e.g. Aufwand, Aufwendung - Bewandtnis, Bewenden - Einwand, Einwendung - Verwendung, Verwandte) but there the meaning will be different.

Comment: I think you do not say explicitly whether they can be used interchangeably.